# Resize DIV to fit page width when printing

Tags: css, highcharts

I have a High Chart which has a width of 100%.

It looks fine on screen but when printing it only prints half of the chart as the other half is over the side of the page.

Is there a way to reduce the size of the chart width so that it fits in when printing?

The High Chart is created by placing a DIV on the page

Thanks for any advice

```
<div id="HighChart" style="height: 350px;"></div>
```

Comment: try `@media only print`

Comment: Instead of resizing div, you can try to resize the chart, see [`chart.events.beforePrint`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.beforePrint) event.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only print{
   #HighChart { width:50%}
}
```